# How many ways to select $4$ people at a round table such that no two of the selected people are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, combinations

> There are $100$ people sited in a circular table with $100$ chairs. How
> many ways to select $4$ such that each chosen person is not adjacent to
> any other chosen person.

---

The problem is equivalent to the following

> Let there be $100$ empty chairs in a circular table. How many ways to choose $4$ chairs such that each chosen chair is not adjacent to any other chair

When it's a straight table, we can remove a chair between each chosen one yielding $\binom{97}{4}$ by bijection argument. It can maybe be applied when the table is circular.

---

I found a solution using PIE

$$\binom{100}{4}-\frac{100\binom{98}{2} \cdot 4-100 \cdot 9 7 \cdot 6+4 \cdot 100}{4}= 3460375$$

Comment: Are the chairs numbered ?

Comment: @trueblueanil no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the part which you say is "equivalent to" the question you want to ask because the original question says $100$ people seated in $100$ chairs. Also when "people" implies distinct entities whereas in the "equivalent" question they are faceless.

If we cut the circle to straighten it out $X ..................Y$, two cases arise: *(i)* we use neither $X$ nor $Y\;$ *(ii)* we use one of $X$ or $Y$

in either case, we have $95$ slots available,

thus the number of ways $= \dbinom{95}4 + 2\dbinom{95}3 = 3460375 $

---

### Extra Answer

You may find this answer even simpler.

$1.$ Remove $4$ chairs and place them in the $96$ interstices.

$2.$ The chairs have only $96$ "starting" places instead of the actual $100$, so multiply by $\frac{100}{96}$

Thus $\dbinom{96}4\dfrac{100}{96} = 3460375$

Answer (score 4):

From the straight table case, subtract the case when both #1 and #100 are selected. When the ends of row are joined to form a circle, we get our desired arrangement.

By the bijection argument, it's $$\binom{97}{4} - \binom{95}{2}$$

> Since it remains to select two non-adjacent chairs from #3 to #98 inclusive ie, 96 chairs.

Comment: My solution with PIE have the same answer. My solution involves 4 chosen chairs which that is named $A,B,C,D$. And then we do PIE on the four sets: A and B together, B and C together, C and D together, and D and A together.